# How can I make a perfect sphere from an imperfect one?

Tags: mesh, remesh

I'm creating a human eyeball in blender 2.91.

When the eyeball is an imperfect sphere, how can I fix it into a perfect sphere without adding or deleting vertices or making a new mesh?[image]

Comment: I realize that I may have misunderstood your question, do you mean that you want to give your object the shape of a sphere or do you want to correct the topology?

Comment: I think both make sense. I'm trying to correct the topology to make it perfect sphere.

Comment: yes but the tricks I explain won't bring back perfect circles, that's what I meant, it will give your object a sphere shape though

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use the *Cast* modifier with a *Factor* of 1:

[image]

You could also use the *Shrinkwrap* modifier with a sphere as *Target*.